# How to launch Spark 2.0 from HDInsight using Azure Automation

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, azure-automation

I can't figure out how to launch HDInsight Spark 2.0 from an Azure Automation graphical runbook. I have an existing runbook that works with HDInsight using Spark 1.6. Normally, I would update the version string from 3.4 to 3.5, but it appears that there are two editions of HDInsight 3.5 - one with Spark 2.0 and one with 1.6.

Can anyone tell me how I can get my runbook to use the Spark2.0 version?

Version Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-component-versioning#hadoop-components-available-with-different-hdinsight-versions

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue. Have you figured this out?

Comment: @Psidom No, I've pinged AzureSupport but still no response.

Comment: @aaronsteers any updates?

Answer (score 1):

I did determine how to do this using an ARM template. Hopefully that will help you with regards to a runbook. Here is the JSON to do a 2.0 cluster. Notice the clusterVersion and componentVersion portions.

```
...
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2015-03-01-preview",
        "name": "somename",
        "type": "Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters",
        "location": "northcentralus",
        "dependsOn": [],
        "properties": {
            "clusterVersion": "3.5",
            "osType": "Linux",
            "tier": "standard",
            "clusterDefinition": {
                "kind": "spark",
                "componentVersion": {
                    "Spark": "2.0"
                },
...
```